# How to realize select specific elements in array while keeping other indices general in python?

Tags: python, numpy

For a rank-4 array, `M[n0,n1,n2,n3]`

I would like to do
`M[m0,m1,:,:]*(some operation)` for all `m0,m1`

or `M[:,m1,:,m3]*(some operation)` for all `m1,m3` with some operation

I can do

```
import numpy as np
import time
n0=2
n1=2
n2=2
n3=2
M = np.zeros((n0,n1,n2,n3))
M2 = np.zeros((n0,n1,n2,n3))
M3 = np.zeros((n0,n1,n2,n3))

i = 0
for m0 in range(M.shape[0]):
    for m1 in range(M.shape[1]):  
        for m2 in range(M.shape[2]):  
            for m3 in range(M.shape[3]):  
                M[m0,m1,m2,m3] = i
                i = i + 1

input = 0


if input == 0:
    for m0 in range(M.shape[0]):
        for m1 in range(M.shape[1]):   
            M2[m0,m1,:,:] =  M[m0,m1,:,:]*(m0+m1)

            
elif input == 1:
    for m1 in range(M.shape[1]):
        for m3 in range(M.shape[3]):  
            M2[:,m1,:,m3] = M[:,m1,:,m3]*(m1-m3)

for m0 in range(M2.shape[0]):
    for m1 in range(M2.shape[1]):  
        for m2 in range(M2.shape[2]):  
            for m3 in range(M2.shape[3]):  
               # M2[m0,m1,m2,m3] = i
                print(m0, m1, m2, m3, 'M', M[m0,m1,m2,m3], 'M2', M2[m0,m1,m2,m3])
```

(using `:` to skip a few loops seems faster than explicitly looping over all indices `m0` - `m3`. That is the motivation for this question: utilize `:`. `m0+m1` and `m1-m3` are somehow randomly picked up)

sample output is

```
0 0 0 0 M 0.0 M2 0.0
0 0 0 1 M 1.0 M2 0.0
0 0 1 0 M 2.0 M2 0.0
0 0 1 1 M 3.0 M2 0.0
0 1 0 0 M 4.0 M2 4.0
0 1 0 1 M 5.0 M2 5.0
0 1 1 0 M 6.0 M2 6.0
0 1 1 1 M 7.0 M2 7.0
1 0 0 0 M 8.0 M2 8.0
1 0 0 1 M 9.0 M2 9.0
1 0 1 0 M 10.0 M2 10.0
1 0 1 1 M 11.0 M2 11.0
1 1 0 0 M 12.0 M2 24.0
1 1 0 1 M 13.0 M2 26.0
1 1 1 0 M 14.0 M2 28.0
1 1 1 1 M 15.0 M2 30.0
```

My question is, is there any simple approach to realize the above code by inputting the position of the target array elements, e.g., 0,1,`M[m0,m1,:.:]` to realize the upper part (`input = 0`) of the code; 1,3 `M[:,m1,:,m3]`for the lower part (`input = 1`) of the above code? And include other cases, e.g., 0,2; 0,3;1,2;2,3. Essentially, change the positions of labels of indices and :.

I can let python print code that includes all cases, but I hope there is something simpler

Comment: Is there any difference between what you are doing now and twice `M *= 1.5`?

Comment: This is a great point. I thought about something more complex in my mind, will edit..

Comment: Can you add an expected input -> output?

Comment: @D.Manasreh I will add some descriptions. Do you think a non-random small dimensional array e.g., 2*2*2*2 will make the question clearer (definite input/output)?

Comment: I think it will

Comment: @D.Manasreh editted. Hopefully looks better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what complex operations you will need, but for now, I think you are not familiar with numpy calculation. To this end, I rewrite the whole answer and complete your three requirements in a simpler and faster way:

```
# Yours
n0 = n1 = n2 = n3 = 2
M = np.zeros((n0, n1, n2, n3))
M2 = np.zeros((n0, n1, n2, n3))
M3 = np.zeros((n0, n1, n2, n3))

i = 0
for m0 in range(M.shape[0]):
    for m1 in range(M.shape[1]):  
        for m2 in range(M.shape[2]):  
            for m3 in range(M.shape[3]):  
                M[m0,m1,m2,m3] = i
                i = i + 1

for m0 in range(M.shape[0]):
    for m1 in range(M.shape[1]):   
        M2[m0,m1,:,:] =  M[m0,m1,:,:]*(m0+m1)


for m1 in range(M.shape[1]):
    for m3 in range(M.shape[3]):  
        M3[:,m1,:,m3] = M[:,m1,:,m3]*(m1-m3)


# Mine
N = np.arange(n0 * n1 * n2 * n3, dtype=float).reshape(n0, n1, n2, n3)
m0, m1, m2, m3 = np.indices(N.shape, sparse=True)
N2 = N * (m0 + m1)
N3 = N * (m1 - m3)
```

You can use the equal sign and the method `ndarray.all` to determine whether two arrays are exactly equal:

```
print((M == N).all())
print((M2 == N2).all())
print((M3 == N3).all())
```

You can try it yourself, they're all `True`.
If you want to know the principle, I can try to write it, but I don't have much time now.

I also want to remind you that when operating numpy arrays, you should avoid using loops as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems this approach takes advantage of *m1*m2*m3*m4. I want something general, that if I need m1,m3 do something, e.g., M[:,m1,:,m3]*m1*m3 + M[:,m1,:,m3]*(m1-m3); or M[m0,m1,:,:] =  M[m0,m1,:,:]*(m0+m1), by either choosing m1 m3 or m0 m1. Will edit my question. Sorry for the confusing

Comment: @Geositta In fact, my method is still valid as long as you want all the elements on one or more axes to be transformed according to their positions on that axis.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am unable to understand what you mean by  `take advantage of broadcast` :(. I will edit my question in the line of new comments from D.Manasreh.

Comment: @Geositta Broadcast is a term for numpy, which is used to make smaller arrays and larger arrays have compatible shapes for some operations. In fact, multiplying an array by a number is an example of broadcasting. It enlarges the number to the same shape as the array, then multiply them element by element.